# sudo add-apt-repository freezes

Tags: 18.04

I messed up and deleted repository file and `.save` file from `sources.list.d`

Now if I try adding repository for example

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa`

It freezes forever how do I restore it to working state?

Comment: can you use synaptic, and refresh there yoiur repository?

Comment: How to use it @JulienChau

Comment: Perhaps you do not have installed synaptic?  It is in the software package :"synaptic package manager).  or you can it simply install it in the terminal  "sudo apt-get install synaptic.  Run it and push the button reload.